# How to identify if the user opened the link to the App store but did not install the app then but later in the future?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Is there any way to know if a user opened the link to your app on the app store from a universal link but did not install it at that time and after say 2-3 days later, installs the app from the app store itself instead of your link.

Currently, when we simulate the same situation at the time of development during the installation of the app via Xcode we still get those parameters. How to identify if the user did install at that moment or at a later point of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any third-party SDK.

I have integrated this feature using [branch.io SDK](https://branch.io/)

Using their Quick Links option you can achieve this.